# Transformation during regression

Tags: python, regression

I need to do a log transformation for a regression problem. is it best practice to log transform X which is the features or Y which is the target variable?

Comment: Is this a predictive model or "causal" like?

Comment: This is a predictive model

Comment: Since it is just a "linear transformation", you can do log() on any single $x$ or to $y$ as long as it is a 'valid' transformation